# Maximo Anywhere Status Change Handler Issue

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I am working on Maximo Anywhere 7.5.2 (Work Execution app). I have added a new status in existing status domain. I am able to see that in Maximo Asset Management but the same domainwostatus is not showing in Anywhere. It always shows the default status options. How to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a site-specific or org-specific domain value, this is a known bug that you can request an iFix for.

If not, make sure you Refresh System Data to redownload the newest Status Domain values to your app after adding the new domain value. This option is available under the Settings page in the overflow menu on the right.

Make sure your new status is a synonym of INPRG or COMP as these rules are used to determine which statuses will show in our lookup.

Comment: Hi Scott, Thnx. I can see that in list and new status is a synonym of INPRG but after selecting the new status, On save, it throws an error that NEWSTATUS is not in value list. Pl hlp.

Comment: Can you attach a breakpoint on our validation to check where that's working.  In Chrome you can simply tell it to break any time there's an exception to easily catch this.  Does restarting the application help any?